# Powershell accessing command line arguments

Tags: powershell, command, line

I have this powershell command that I use to open up a kitty/PuTTY session. 
THe format is

```
.\my_sshCommand three
```

Which in this case should take me to server.three, but no matter what command line argument I put in it takes me to server.TWO. The idea is that if there are not parameters on the command line, then server.TWO will be the default. I really don't know how to make a loop in powershell, so I just hardcode out the commands. I just cant figure why the command always fulfills the else clause no matter what command line argument I put in the script.

```
param(
   [array] $ComputerName
)



ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
   IF($Computer -match 'one') {
   $Computer="server.one"
   Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   $Command="c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   }
   IF($Computer -match 'two') {
   $Computer="server.TWO"
   Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   $Command="c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   }
   IF($Computer -match 'three') {
   $Computer="server.three"
   Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   $Command="c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   }
   IF($Computer -match 'four') {
   $Computer="server.four"
   Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   $Command="c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
   }
   ELSE {
   Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@server.TWO -pw pizza"
   $Command="c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@server.TWO -pw pizza"
   }
}



Invoke-Expression $Command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The else on the last comparison is tripping you up.

Since three doesn't match 'four', it's hitting the else, and sending you to .two.

Here's a solution using switch:

```
param(
    [array] $ComputerName
)

ForEach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    switch ($computer) { 
        'one' {
            $Computer = "server.one"
            Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
            $Command = "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
        }
        'two' {
            $Computer = "server.TWO"
            Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
            $Command = "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
        }
        'three' {
            $Computer = "server.three"
            Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
            $Command = "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
        }
        'four' {
            $Computer = "server.four"
            Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
            $Command = "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@$Computer -pw pizza"
        }
        default {
            Write-Output "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@server.TWO -pw pizza"
            $Command = "c:\Working\Kitty.exe -load `"capser profile`" -ssh capser@server.TWO -pw pizza"
        }
    }
}
```